# how to change height DataTable PrimeReact

Tags: javascript, html, css, primereact

I can't stretch the table to the entire height of the block, even with one record
I am using PrimeReact in my app, here is my code:

```
            <DataTable
                value={dataArr}
                headerColumnGroup={headerGroup}
                paginator
                rows={1}
                rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 50]}
                rowHover
                responsiveLayout="scroll"
                showGridlines
                stripedRows
                resizableColumns
                
            >
....
            </DataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `responsiveLayout="scroll"` you want to set `scrollHeight="200px"` or whatever height you want.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-estrela-jvzoei?file=/src/demo/DataTablePaginatorDemo.js

Comment: This does not work

Comment: Updated my answer see my Code Sandbox reproducer.